# Looking for a rails gem for simple BI tasks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I'm imagining a rails gem that I can feed with a list of SQL queries such as `count (*) from users where active = 1` and this gem would provide a rake task that I can run as a daily cron job and have a graphic interface that plots the results as a graph. For example, one graph for number of daily active users, another graph for number of new registrations etc. A very simple and basic BI for my rails database.
It might be simple enough to implement, still, I'd be happy to find a prepackaged gem.
Googling didn't find one, anyone knows one?
thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several gems for reporting : https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/reporting